# UserWarning: FigureCanvasAgg is non-interactive, and thus cannot be shown plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am using

- Windows 10
- PyCharm 2021.3.3 Professional Edition
- python 3.11.5
- matplotlib 3.8.1

How can I permanently resolve this issue in my development environment?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read data from file, skipping the first row (header)
data = np.loadtxt('cm.dat', skiprows=1)

# Initialize reference point
x0, y0, z0 = data[0]

# Compute squared displacement for each time step
SD = [(x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2 + (z - z0)**2 for x, y, z in data]

# Compute the cumulative average of SD to get MSD at each time step
MSD = np.cumsum(SD) / np.arange(1, len(SD) + 1)

# Generate time steps
t = np.arange(1, len(SD) + 1)

# Create a log-log plot of MSD versus t
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.loglog(t, MSD, marker='o')

plt.title('Mean Squared Displacement vs Time')
plt.xlabel('Time step')
plt.ylabel('MSD')
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="--")
plt.show()
```

```
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:/git/RouseModel/tau_plot.py
C:\git\RouseModel\tau_plot.py:29: UserWarning: FigureCanvasAgg is non-interactive, and thus cannot be shown
  plt.show()

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: And you want interactive plots, not plots in the plot viewer?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, I only want to see the plot, no interactiveness is required.

Comment: `matplotlib.use('Agg')` this is not needed for normal plotting. This Warning is still generated if 'Agg' set, but it's not need. Update PyCharm.

Comment: I tried `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`, also install PyQt5, it works for me

Answer (score 20):

I have the same issue. In my case, I installed the PyQt5==5.15.10. After that, I run my code successfully.

`pip install PyQt5==5.15.10` or `pip install PyQt5`

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue when running my code from a virtual environment venv in Ubuntu. I tried with PyQt5 but did not work. I managed to solve the problem by installing PySide2

```bash
pip install PySide2
```

Answer (score 2):

In your development environment, you could use the [default backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/backends.html#the-builtin-backends) which uses python's builtin [Tkinter module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html), an interface to the Tcl/Tk GUI toolkit.

So the fix would be to delete the line:

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

If you still get the error, it probably means you don't have tkinter installed. You can make sure of that by running: `python -m tkinter`.

Tkinter normally comes pre-installed with Python.
If you opted out Tcl/Tk installation when you installed Python, you can run the python installer again and choose "modify" to install only Tcl/Tk. See screenshot: [python-installer-options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BStqc.png)

Comment: I have tkinter installed and the problem persists.

Comment: thanks for 
> you don't have tkinter installed
. in linux: 'sudo apt-get install python3-tk'

Answer (score 0):

In **matplotlibrc** uncomment this line:

backend: TkAgg